# How does dateadd, datetime and datediff works together?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff

Can someone please help me understand this snippet of code:

```
DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, CONVERT(datetime, 
er.DATE_EFFECTIVE)) + 2, 0))
```

Comment: [The best choice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: What part(s) don't you understand? It returns the last day of the next month from DATE_EFFECTIVE

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It'll help you understand if you break it apart... run this...`select
 CONVERT(datetime, er.DATE_EFFECTIVE) --Your Date
 ,DATEDIFF(mm, 0, CONVERT(datetime,er.DATE_EFFECTIVE))
 ,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, CONVERT(datetime,er.DATE_EFFECTIVE)) + 2,0)
 ,DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, CONVERT(datetime,er.DATE_EFFECTIVE)) + 2, 0)) FROM yourTable er`

Comment: datetime is a data type, DateDiff is the distance between two datetimes according to whatever the first parameter is (mm for month, day for day, etc), and DateAdd will give you a new datetime that is adjusted according to the first two parameters. DateAdd (dd, -1, targetColumn) will give you one day earlier than targetColumn is set to.

Comment: Thank you Cody McPheron. I appreciate it, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer for other users that might be seeking out help. So please refer to Cody McPheron's comment:

- datetime is a data type
- DateDiff is the distance between two datetimes according to 
  whatever the first parameter is (mm for month, day for day, etc)
- DateAdd will give you a new datetime that is adjusted according to the first two 
  parameters.
- DateAdd (dd, -1, targetColumn) will give you one day earlier than targetColumn is set 
  to